# Carbon date bug on php 7.0

Tags: php, date, php-carbon

I'm having a problem with composer package illuminate/database and Carbon on PHP 7.0.24.

Sometimes php is producing the following exception

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2018-03-09 16:56:16.-51861) at position 24 (6): Unexpected character in /volume1/web/octopus/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php:413
Stack trace:
#0 /volume1/web/octopus/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php(413): DateTime->__construct('2018-03-09 16:5...', Object(DateTimeZone))
1 /volume1/web/octopus/global_bootstrap.php(48): Carbon\Carbon->__construct()
2 /volume1/web/octopus/app/bootstrap.php(8): require_once('/volume1/web/oc...')
3 /volume1/web/octopus/app/dashboard.php(8): require('/volume1/web/oc...')
4 {main}
thrown in /volume1/web/octopus/vendor/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php on line 413
```

if I only create an instance of Carbon without any parameters like this

```
<?php
// ...composer initialization...
$carbon = new \Carbon\Carbon();
var_dump($carbon);
```

After looking deeper into Carbon-class there is an if clause for php versions lower than 7.1 which adds microtime behind a string formatted date, but why?

Is there a bug in carbon for php versions lower than 7.1?

Comment: Not very helpful, but see https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/issues/1157

Comment: If there might be a bug, why don't you report it in the official bugtracker?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding two lines at the top of my php script:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'de_DE@euro', 'de_DE', 'deu_deu');
// ....
$carbon = new \Carbon\Carbon();
var_dump($carbon);
```